# Dragging from a collection view works on the iPad, but not on the iPhone. How come?

Tags: ios, iphone

I've been implementing the new drag and drop functionality in iOS 11, specifically for a collection view. Right now things work on the iPad, but not on the iPhone. I'm aware that you can only drag and drop within the same app on the iPhone; that's what I'm trying to do.

For some reason `collectionView(_:itemsForBeginning:at:)` isn't called when I attempt to perform a drag. Works fine on the iPad. Thoughts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had to set `collectionView.dragInteractionEnabled = true`

> The default value of this property is true on iPad and false on
>   iPhone. Changing the value to true on iPhone makes it possible to drag
>   content from the collection view to another app on iPhone and to
>   receive content from other apps.

Comment: I had a similar problem with adding dragging to a normal UIView. It works on iPad but not on iPhone. I tried looking for a similar property like dragInteractionEnabled but to no avail.